# Prove that there exists a circle $q$ orthogonal to the x axis.

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I have been stuck on this problem for hours.

I have an ideal hyperbolic triangle with vertices at $A=(a,0), B=(b,0), C=(c,0)$ where $0<a,b,c$.

[image: Here is my drawing of it.]

The question asks to prove that there exists a circle $q$ orthogonal to the x-axis so that $I_q(A)=(0,0)$ and
$I_q(C) = \infty$.

Here is what I can deduce from this. The center of $q$ must  be $C$. I don't know what I can do with the fact that $I_q(A)=(0,0)$ because $A$ here is arbitrary.

Comment: To be clear: "$I_q(P)$" stands for "the inversion of $P$ in $q$", correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: Okay, so you know the center of inversion is $C$. All you need is the radius. What do you know about how this radius, call it $r$, relates to the distances $|CA|$ and $|CO|$ (where $O$ is the origin)? How can you write those distances in terms of $a$ and $c$?